# AngularJS (yeoman generator) using ng-boostrap library import problem

Tags: angularjs, ng-bootstrap, yeoman-generator-angular

I've built an angular project using yeoman generator [see there](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular)

```
yo angular testapp
```

I've used bower to install the ng-boostrap library.

```
bower install ng-bootstrap
```

Normally, I import the ".js" file to my "index.html" file and add the module name into my "app.js" file like below :

```js
angular
  .module('testApp', [
    modules names...
  ])
```

I don't know how am I supposed to use the library (can't find any ".js" to include) ? I've red the documentation from ng-bootstrap official website and yeoman angular generator aswell but i'm still stuck on the problem.

Comments or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Might be because ng-bootstrap is built for Angular (V2.X onwards) and is based on typescript (.ts) while AngularJS is based on vanilla JS. Sounds like what you're after is [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I've added `ui-bootstrap` and it's works fine.

Comment: I've posted the same stuff as an answer. Please mark it as preferred answer :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be because ng-bootstrap is built for Angular (V2.X onwards) and is based on typescript (.ts).

AngularJS (V1.X) is based on vanilla JS (.js). 
Sounds like what you're after is [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)